# How to share netns between different containers in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I want to share the netns between two containers which belong to the same pod.
I know all containers in the same pod share the network by default. And I try to mount the same host path to `/var/run/netns` for both containers. I can create netns in first container, but when I access the netns in second container, it says "Invalid argument". I run `"file /var/run/netns/n1"`, it reports normal empty file. What can I do? Is it possible?

Comment: The `ns1` file is the pseudo-file in the `nsfs` filesystem.
What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

But below manifest file works perfectly in my case. You can check also by following steps.

Step 1: kubectl apply -f (below manifest file)

Step 2: kubectl exec -ti test-pd -c test1 /bin/bash

Step 3: go to test-pd directory and create a .txt file using touch command and exit.

Step 4: kubectl exec -ti test-pd -c test2 sh

Spep 5: go to test-pd directory and check the created file here. I found the created file here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: test1
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  - image: pkbhowmick/go-rest-api:2.0.1
    name: test2
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Comment: This is what I do now. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please make sure '/var/run/netns' path exists in both container.

Comment: Sure. I run "ip netns add n1" in first container, I can see the file "/var/run/netns/n1" in container2, but when I run "ip netns exec n1 ip link", it says "Invalid argument".

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check now. I checked and things were working in my case.

Comment: Yes. It works with normal file case. But netns file is not only a normal file, there is a nsfs mounted to it. And the mouting is not visible to another container.